# How do I delete my account

Tags: user-account

I have not used my civicrm account for many many years.  Today I got 139 password reset email notifications.  I don't want to have to deal with this, I just want to delete the account.

If you have someone to whom I can forward some of these emails, I"m happy to do so.  Just let me know to whom I should forward it.

Obviously, I can't login again because someone/something has changed my password.

Peace
CJ Rhoads

Comment: What website is your compromised account on? I'm unclear exactly what you're asking about, but in general a good way to get your account deleted off a given site is to contact the site administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about your account at civicrm.org

There's no way for users to delete their accounts - you can unsubscribe from emails, which I think you have done.

There's a contact email at https://civicrm.org/contact - you can send your request to that.